# Null reference exception when filling an multidimensional image array

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2012, multidimensional-array, nullreferenceexception

I create the Array cardImages in Class KartenClass

```
public Image[][][] cardImages = new Image[9][][];
```

I wrote a method called arrbef() to fill it

```
public void arrbef()
{ 
    this.cardImages[0][0] = new Image[3] { global::WindowsFormsApplication4.Properties.Resources.Card, global::WindowsFormsApplication4.Properties.Resources.CardBack, global::WindowsFormsApplication4.Properties.Resources.CardSet };
    this.cardImages[0][1] = new Image[3] { global::WindowsFormsApplication4.Properties.Resources.Card, global::WindowsFormsApplication4.Properties.Resources.CardBack, 
etc....
```

and in my Form i call the method arrbef and try to fill it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Karten : Form
    {
        KartenClass karten = new KartenClass();
        int standort = 0;

        public Karten()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KartenClass.karten[0].arrbef();
        }
```

But when i click on the button which links to this form, i get the following Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei WindowsFormsApplication4.KartenClass.arrbef() in c:\Users\david.kresse\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\KartenClass.cs:Zeile 24.
   bei WindowsFormsApplication4.Karten..ctor() in c:\Users\david.kresse\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\Karten.cs:Zeile 22.
   bei WindowsFormsApplication4.Start.btnStartGoToKarten_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\david.kresse\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\Start.cs:Zeile 394.
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

What did i do wrong? I did exactly the same with another array (which was one dimensonal).

I hope you can help.

Comment: What is the length of `this.cardImages[0]` :) ?

Comment: It's always best to turn on break on throw in the debugger settings. Then you can get a callstack when the problem happens, and you can learn how to debug it yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
public Image[][][] cardImages = new Image[9][][];
```

... creates a top level array with 9 elements in. Every element value is null. You need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cardImages.Length; i++) {
    cardImages[i] = new Image[???][]; // What length do you want?
}
```

Then you can populate `cardImages[0][0]` etc as you're doing.

Personally I'd try to avoid 3-dimensional arrays (or arrays of arrays of arrays in this case) - it can get messy. It may be appropriate in this case though; it's hard to say without more information.

EDIT: With more information, it may make sense to model this as a `Category[]` (or `List<Category>`) where a `Category` has a `Card[]` or `List<Card>`, and a `Card` has an `Image[]` or `List<Image>`. Then at the top level you just have a collection of categories.

Comment: the array contains 9 categories with 20 cards, each with 3 conditions.

Comment: @user3086972: See my edit for how I'd model it then - by making the meaning of each level clear, the whole code becomes clearer.

Comment: Okay thank you, i will try that. I think i will have to hit a few tutorials for that though. But i´m on it! Big thanks to you my friend! :)

Comment: I tried it with the for-loop and it works perfectly. I will try it again with lists as soon as i learned how to do it. :)